# Is there any way to parse the json(without parsing schema) while reading from kafa in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to send a json string from kafka  and save it in hdfs json files using spark structured streaming programming.

For example My input as follows:

```
{
"customerId":1
"Name":"xyz"
"dept":"IT"
}
```

my output should be stored all data came from streaming in a single file in some interval.

```
{
"customerId":1
"Name":"xyz"
"dept":"IT"
}{
"customerId":1
"Name":"xyz"
"dept":"IT"
}
```

But I am getting below output:

```
"value":{
"customerId":1
"Name":"xyz"
"dept":"IT"
}
"value":{
"customerId":1
"Name":"xyz"
"dept":"IT"
}
```

I want to remove the value option.
I know its coming from kafka .
**If i tried with schema its working fine.But my schema should be dynamic for each customer with dept wise.**
Any help will be appreciated.

Below are the sample code base:

```
val inputDf = spark.read.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","hd0-dn01.com:9091").option("subscribe","topic1").load()

val dataDf = inputDf.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

dataDf.writeStream.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)).format("console").option("truncate",false).outputMode("append").start().awaitTermination()
```

Comment: What do you mean without a schema? `AS STRING` is your schema for the code shown

Comment: Without a schema means without any class like in this case customer is an object.like this i need output like below.{
"customerId":1
"Name":"xyz"
"dept":"IT"
}{
"customerId":1
"Name":"xyz"
"dept":"IT"
}   value shouldn't come in my json file.

Comment: Have you tried selecting `value.*` from the dataframe?